# Put delay in time while running the chronometer

Tags: android, countdown, chronometer

I have an android app in which count up timer is included I used a chronometer for it.....

Now there is a scenario that after every 10 sec, 1 sec should change in chronometer I used `handler.postdelyed()` but in this, the chronometer starts running after 10 sec but the timer of chronometer starts from 10 sec, not 1 sec. Is there any method that I can make count up timer with delay in it.

Here is my code:

```
chronometer_life_gained.setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChronometerTick(final Chronometer chronometer) {
        long delay = (206 / Long.parseLong(joint_per_day))*1000;
        System.out.println("delayer " + delay);
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
        if ((SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase()) < 60000) {
            long dy = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase());
            final long hr = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase())
                    - TimeUnit.DAYS.toHours(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase()));
            final long min = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase())
                    - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase()));
            final long sec = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase())
                    - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase()));

            year_num_life_gained.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            year_text_life_gained.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            month_num_life_gained.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            month_text_life_gained.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            day_num_life_gained.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            day_text_life_gained.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            hour_num_life_gained.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            hour_text_life_gained.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            min_num_life_gained.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            min_text_life_gained.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            sec_num_life_gained.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            sec_text_life_gained.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START);
            sec_num_life_gained.setLayoutParams(params);

            sec_num_life_gained.setText(Long.toString(sec));


        }
//
            }
        }, delay);

//    }

    }
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it with `CountDownTimer`, although it is by name **count down timer**, but we can make it work to count up.

```
// Counter variable to show seconds increment
int counter = 4000;

// If you want to count until 60 seconds, put VALUE_IN_MILLIS_UNTIL_YOU_WANT_TO_COUNT_UP = 60000 (in milliseconds)
elapsedTimer = new CountDownTimer(VALUE_IN_MILLIS_UNTIL_YOU_WANT_TO_COUNT_UP, 5000) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long l) {
// Logically, we need 
long elapsedTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - startTime - counter;
        long dy = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(elapsedTime);
        final long yr = dy / 365;
        dy %= 365;

        final long mn = dy / 30;
        dy %= 30;

        final long hr = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(elapsedTime)
                - TimeUnit.DAYS.toHours(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(elapsedTime));
        final long min = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(elapsedTime)
                - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(elapsedTime));
        final long sec = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(elapsedTime)
                - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(elapsedTime));
        // add 4000 as 4 seconds to counter value
        counter = counter + 4000;
        txView.setText(counter + " second");
    }
}.start();
```

Comment: what is use of elapsed time here?

Comment: `elapsedTime` is time from starting timer. This code is working for me.

Comment: why counter is incrementing 4 second

Comment: As you want that every 5 seconds, you need 1 second difference in UI. So, I have added this logically. This code would work

Answer (score 0):

```
private Runnable updateTimerMethod = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        long elapsedTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - startTime;
        long dy = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(elapsedTime);
        final long yr = dy / 365;
        dy %= 365;

        final long mn = dy / 30;
        dy %= 30;

        final long hr = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(elapsedTime)
                - TimeUnit.DAYS.toHours(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(elapsedTime));
        final long min = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(elapsedTime)
                - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(elapsedTime));
        final long sec = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(elapsedTime)
                - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(elapsedTime));

        myHandler.postDelayed(this, 2000);
    }

};
```

Comment: This code is working for me. I put a delay in timer that what i want and delay is also ok but now there is a problem that if i put delay of 2 seconds then timer changes from 1 to 3 sec not 1 to 2 sec

Comment: Keep it to `1000` as delay.

Comment: i know but i want to keep a delay i want that every second should pass after 5 seconds

Comment: You can easily do that with my answer, only pass `5000` (5 seconds) in place of `1000` in `CountDownTimer` constructor. So, you'll get `onTick()` callback in each 5 seconds interval, from where you can update your `TextView` by incrementing 1 seconds. To do that, I am editing my answer

Comment: @Kushal can u help me?

Comment: canyou completely write your answer..may be i m missing something

Comment: Please check my answer

Comment: @Kushal what is value of elapsed timer?\

Comment: I've completely added your logic, please check again. Sorry for back and forth